# Does capitalization change the meaning of the word coke?

Tags: meaning, capitalization

Does capitalization change the meaning of the word *coke*? Does *Coke* mean the soda and *coke* mean the drug? Is there a grammar term that denotes this behavior? Or is there no rule and it's simply the context that defines the definition?

Comment: The first meaning of 'coke' to me is the by-product of coal from which gas has been extracted and which is burned as a smokeless fuel. But it could be that it is called something other than that in America.

Comment: @WS2 Huh. I have never heard of that definition until you mentioned. Had to go to consult a dictionary.

Comment: 'Coke™'  is a registered trademark, it should always be capitalised as it was registered like that! Nothing to do with grammar I think!

Comment: Coke: pronoun, "Would you like to have a Coke?"  coke: noun, "Would you like to sniff some coke?"  It is contextual based for the noun. "Would you like to burn some coke?"  The soft-drink reference will always be capitalized and no other usage (that I'm aware of) will. The answer to your question "Does capitalization change the meaning of the word *coke*?" is yes.

Comment: Based on regional preferences, in the Southeastern U.S. it is quite common for the term "coke" to be used in exchange for any variety of soda that the person is speaking of, and not just the brand "Coke". e.g. "I'm going to pick up some coke from the grocery store, what kind would you like?" -- "I'll take Dr. Pepper, if they have it."

Comment: @Juice So what do you call smokeless fuel?

Comment: @WS2 - Electricity.

Comment: @phenry Ha ha! full marks for wit. But I'm talking about the by-product of coal which is burned in hearths or braziers. They must have it in America. What do they call it?

Comment: @WS2 Hardly anyone burns coal at home in the U.S., at least not for some decades. I think coal was never as prevalent a home heating fuel here; firewood was cheap and plentiful, gas lighting became popular just as the country started to expand, and electric lighting was invented shortly after industrialization here got underway. But a properly educated American should remember coke as one contributing factor in the rise of Andrew Carnegie (specifically, his exploitation of the Bessemer process to reduce the amount of coke needed to produce steel).

Comment: @choster So you do call it coke! Few people burn solid fuel at home in Britain nowadays. But in the 1950s domestic coal burning was the cause of the dreadful London smog. They passed a Clean Air Act enforcing a smokeless fuel and the effect was dramatic. No more smog. But the vast majority of homes in the UK now use natural gas, with minorities using oil and electricity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *Coke* is a trademark of the Coca-Cola Company. It is a proper noun and should always be capitalized. The word *coke*, meaning either cocaine or a by-product of coal or oil distillation, is not a proper noun and should not be capitalized except as normal English-language capitalization rules dictate.

Comment: What about the Southern usage of *coke* as any carbonated beverage?

Comment: My recollection is that that's primarily a spoken usage. I believe that in the South, *Coke* as a generic term is highly informal (not to mention a violation of an actively used trademark), so I wouldn't expect to see it used at all in more formal written language, such as news articles. I make no claims as to the standards used by, say, restaurant menus--but then, I wouldn't point to restaurant menus as examples of exemplary language usage anyway.

Comment: @KitFox The case you presented is what is known as a generic (or genericized) trademark.  There are a number of interesting examples, including aspirin, heroin, kerosene, and many more.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks

Comment: Stupid question, but what do Southerners say when they mean Coke? Cola?